# Working with Const all through activity to store values?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 classes Const , Users , FacebookProfile and Test class. I have managed to get the biodata from facebook. I want to save the biodata to the Const so that on the Test class I can manage to maybe to Toast the fname through Const.getName();

```
public class Users implements Serializable {

    String fname , lname ;

    public String getFname(){
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname){
        this.fname = fname;

    }
    public String getLname(){
    return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname){
    this.lname = lname;
}



}
```

The next class is Const for saving the data

```
public final class Const  {

Users users;

public Users getUsers(){
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Users users){

    this.users = users;
}


private Const() {
    init();
}

public static Const getInstance() {
    return ConstHolder.INSTANCE;
}

private void init() {
    this.getUsers();
}

private static class ConstHolder {
    private static final Const INSTANCE = new Const();
}



}
```

Comment: "How do i save it on const to be accessed anywhere on the app" - In this case I'd consider it bad praxis, however you can check up on the [Singleton pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html). I'd vote against using a Singleton. I would instead pass the reference of `Const` or thinking of adding a database to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my Quize  is so simple using Const through your app all along

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button , button1;


        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttondata);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = "Alex";
                String lname = "Boey";
                Users users = new Users();
                users.setFname(name);
                users.setLname(lname);
                Const.getInstance().setUsers(users);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,Const.getInstance().getUsers().getFname().toString() + Const.getInstance().getUsers().getLname(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Nothing found in the Const" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });



    }


}
```